# How may one opt?

Tags: idioms

I would like to write that one should opt for one version over another. May I do so, while writing good English, or are there important cautions?

Answer (score 2):

"... should opt for one version over another. ..." is perfectly sensible.

Example:

"Version 9 of the software application contains improvements over version 8. If you have a choice of the two versions for installation, you should opt to install version 9."

Comment: But you don't give an example.

Comment: Edited my answer to include an example under the _word_ "Example" instead of the abbreviation "Ex:" which denotes ... an example.

Comment: That is not an example of occurrences of "opt for one version over another".